# same content doesn't display in different browsers

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter.I add a footer to my view php page using HTML and include the "footer.php" to my main view php page here the footer.php HTML and php code

```
<div class="col-sm-2 ">

                <!-- Stay Connected -->
                <div class="footer-heading">
                    <h2>Stay Connected</h2>
                </div> 

                <ul class="social-icons">
                    <li><a href="#" data-original-title="Facebook" class="social_facebook"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-original-title="Twitter" class="social_twitter"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-original-title="Goole Plus" class="social_googleplus"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-original-title="Youtube" class="social_youtube"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-original-title="Linkedin" class="social_linkedin"></a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="app-icons">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets_profile/img/icons/google_play.png" >
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets_profile/img/icons/apps_store.png" >
                </div>

            </div>
```

but the problem is,in chrome browser display like this every thing i added 
[image]

[image]
but in the Firefox browser  display like this

how can fix this problem? need quick help and this the my css code

```
    .social_amazon {background: url(../img/icons/social/amazon.png) no-repeat;}
.social_behance {background: url(../img/icons/social/behance.png) no-repeat;}
.social_blogger {background: url(../img/icons/social/blogger.png) no-repeat;}
.social_deviantart {background: url(../img/icons/social/deviantart.png) no-repeat;}
.social_dribbble {background: url(../img/icons/social/dribbble.png) no-repeat;}
.social_dropbox {background: url(../img/icons/social/dropbox.png) no-repeat;}
.social_evernote {background: url(../img/icons/social/evernote.png) no-repeat;}
.social_facebook {background: url(../img/icons/social/facebook.png) no-repeat;}
.social_forrst {background: url(../img/icons/social/forrst.png) no-repeat;}
.social_github {background: url(../img/icons/social/github.png) no-repeat;}
.social_googleplus {background: url(../img/icons/social/googleplus.png) no-repeat;}
.social_jolicloud {background: url(../img/icons/social/jolicloud.png) no-repeat;}
.social_last-fm {background: url(../img/icons/social/last-fm.png) no-repeat;}
.social_linkedin {background: url(../img/icons/social/linkedin.png) no-repeat;}
.social_picasa {background: url(../img/icons/social/picasa.png) no-repeat;}
.social_pintrest {background: url(../img/icons/social/pintrest.png) no-repeat;}
.social_rss {background: url(../img/icons/social/rss.png) no-repeat;}
.social_skype {background: url(../img/icons/social/skype.png) no-repeat;}
.social_spotify {background: url(../img/icons/social/spotify.png) no-repeat;}
.social_stumbleupon {background: url(../img/icons/social/stumbleupon.png) no-repeat;}
.social_tumblr {background: url(../img/icons/social/tumblr.png) no-repeat;}
.social_twitter {background: url(../img/icons/social/twitter.png) no-repeat;}
.social_vimeo {background: url(../img/icons/social/vimeo.png) no-repeat;}
.social_wordpress {background: url(../img/icons/social/wordpress.png) no-repeat;}
.social_xing {background: url(../img/icons/social/xing.png) no-repeat;}
.social_yahoo {background: url(../img/icons/social/yahoo.png) no-repeat;}
.social_youtube {background: url(../img/icons/social/youtube.png) no-repeat;}
.social_vk {background: url(../img/icons/social/vk.png) no-repeat;}
```

Comment: doubtful that it has anything to do with the background images and more to do with the associated positioning of these elements. can you make a jsFiddle replicating this please?

Comment: I didn't get it,i never did any change background images only add footer to my page

Answer (score 0):

I think given path is wrong,
try this,

```
.social_amazon {
background: url(<?php echo base_url();?>img/icons/social/amazon.png) no-repeat;
}
```